# Subsequent bounties

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to start another bounty for

> [Is the "Zion Archive" (Animatrix) Machine Propaganda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12369/2565)

There was already a 250 rep bounty some time ago, but I'm *still* not happy with the answers (as does the community, judging from the votes). However, I can only select 500 rep (I would prefer to go with about 100 +- 50). Why is that the case? This certainly doesn't seem like a bug, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to limit additional bounties to 500 rep, does it?

I tagged this as discussion, although if the community agrees could be promoted to a feature-request.

Answer (score 2):

On very popular topics on Stack Overflow, setting a bounty on a question that you have answered has been known to bring in more reputation than the bounty cost. This has motivated a restriction in the bounty system: if you set a second bounty on a question that you previously set a bounty on, then the amount of the second bounty must be at least double the amount of the first bounty. See ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

I am against this restriction, which is undermining the bounty system in order to solve something that is not really a problem in the first place, and can only take place in very unusual circumstances. But I am powerless to rescind it.

Comment: Why? Isn't the SO system separate from SFF?

Comment: @bitmask The rules are the same on all sites, with very few exceptions, and this isn't one.

Comment: Do you know if it's limited? I mean, 1k is a lot to "spend" on a question, but just out of curiosity, will awarding 500 mean that there will never be another bounty or does it mean that the next bounty would be 1k?

Comment: @bitmask 500 is the maximum amount for a bounty. See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)